# Which Sphinx gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

I working on my first Rails app with Sphinx and I've run into trouble with the [Sphinx gem](https://github.com/kpumuk/sphinx):

```
Sphinx::SphinxInternalError: searchd error: client version is higher than daemon version (client is v.1.29, daemon is v.1.25)
```

Rails 3.2.13, sphinx gem 2.1.1.3212, Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473).

Other Sphinx gems indicate a sphinx.yml file, I'm not seeing that with this gem.

Is there a consensus "best" gem for Sphinx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking Sphinx is probably the most used.

The current version is 3.0, which is documented in the README file:
https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/

The "official" documentation still refers to the older version, which works differently:
http://pat.github.com/ts/en/

For new code the newer version is recommended.

Comment: You're welcome - although, if it was useful, I would appreciate an upvote for the answer and/or choosing it as the accepted one.